# Virtual propagation on destructor

Tags: c++, polymorphism, destructor

I know that `virtual` propagates to the derived class method and it's optional to put as keyword on the method declaration on the derived class, and i know that i MUST mark as `virtual` the destructor of the base class, in order to have polymorphic destruction, but what i want to know is if the default destructor of the derived class, inherit the `virtual` from the virtual destructor of the base class, and so i have to explicit write it on the derived class.

Example:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual ~A() override = default;
}
class B: public A{
public:
    // have i to write this or it's already what the compiler get as default?
    virtual ~B() override = default;
}
```

Comment: oh yeah sorry @rustyx

Comment: Your example code triggers a compiler error because `~A()` does not override anything. *(Remove the `override` keyword from that declaration? Maybe from `~B()` as well since having both `virtual` and `override` in the same declaration is overkill and you need `virtual` to illustrate your question.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructor for a derived class, despite having a different name from the destructor of the base class, **overrides** the base class destructor. Just like any other override, it’s virtual if the one it overrides is virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes once a member function (destructor included) is marked as [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Virtual_destructor) in the base class, it remains `virtual` in all derived classes.

You can omit the keyword `virtual` in `~B()` declaration, and even omit `~B()` entirely, if it's empty.

Comment: yes my question is born because i've read that C++  on runtime try to find the full method structure "match" , so same name, parameters, const ecc ecc (except for pointer that accept also derived), and so destructor wasn't one of those because they have different names

Comment: A destructor has no name; it's just the C++ syntax that requires `~<class_name>`. However, the term *overrides* is often confusing in this context, as virtual destructors don't actually *override* but stack up on top of each other, forming a cleanup chain.